# How to show pylint message codes/ids in PyCharm Problems view and get quick fix?

Tags: python, pycharm, pylint

I get some pylint warnings in the Problems view of PyCharm Community Edition:

[image]

**a)** How can I tell PyCharm to include the corresponding message code/id in the **Problems** View, so that I am able to manually suppress the warning without manually searching the corresponding message code/id?

**b)** How can I teach PyCharm to provide a quick fix for suppressing the warning with a line comment?

For example

"PyLint: Too many local variables"

=>

`# pylint: disable=too-many-locals`

Related:

[List of pylint human readable message ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955361/list-of-pylint-human-readable-message-ids)

[How to show pylint message codes in VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585271/how-to-show-pylint-message-codes-in-vscode)

[How do I automatically fix lint issues reported by pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586757/how-do-i-automatically-fix-lint-issues-reported-by-pylint)

[Visual Studio Code quick-fix & python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582277/visual-studio-code-quick-fix-python)

*Edit*

Also see related issue ticket of PyCharm Pylint Plugin:

https://github.com/leinardi/pylint-pycharm/issues/92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the standard **Problems** view does not show the message ids, the extra **Pylint** view does (after running a scan):

[image]

Unfortunately, quick fixes are not provided by that view.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to

> b) How can I teach PyCharm to provide a quick fix for suppressing the warning with a line comment?

Is sadly: Go back and wait at https://github.com/leinardi/pylint-pycharm/issues/92 (or someone starts implementing it . and, btw, upstream actually accepts that OR someone goes ahead and creates a yet-another new plugin)

Answer (score 0):

There do not seem be alternative PyLint Plugins for PyCharm. Unfortunately, for `VsCodium` (Visual Studio Code without tracking) the situation seems to be similar.

Well, there is the extension ms-python and it supports many linting tools for Python (Strg+Shift+P: Python: Select linter).

For PyLint it shows the message ids in the VsCodium PROBLEMS view.

[image]

If the language server would be set to `Pylance`, Quick fixes for PyLint would be available, too.

Unfortunately, the language server Pylance does not support `VSCodium`:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/791

Related:

[Visual Studio Code quick-fix & python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582277/visual-studio-code-quick-fix-python)